# Pseudo keyframe animation not working

Tags: wordpress, css-animations, pseudo-class, keyframe

I am new to keyframes and am trying to get an animation to run on a pseudo element in wordpress. I cannot work out why it is not working.

I have read through similar questions and forums but to no avail.

I am actually eventually wanting it to move left and right but I just grabbed some spin keyframes to test it.

The code I have tried is:

```
.dots::after {
    content: url("/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/pub-crawl-edinburgh-hand-01.svg");
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    transform: translateY(32px);
    margin-right: 80px;
    animation: spin .5s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: spin .5s infinite linear;    
    -webkit-animation: spin .5s infinite linear; 
    -o-animation: spin .5s infinite linear;    
    -ms-animation: spin .5s infinite linear;    
    -moz-animation:spin .5s infinite linear;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
   0% { -moz-transform:rotate(0deg); }
   100% { -moz-transform:rotate(360deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
   0% { -moz-transform:rotate(0deg); }
   100% { -moz-transform:rotate(360deg); }
}

@-o-keyframes spin {
   0% { -moz-transform:rotate(0deg); }
   100% { -moz-transform:rotate(360deg); }
}

@-ms-keyframes spin {
   0% { -moz-transform:rotate(0deg); }
   100% { -moz-transform:rotate(360deg); }
}
```

I tried removing the initial transform as I thought maybe that was the issue and tried applying it to various other objects including elements that were not pseudo classes and even tried it on another website but it just doesn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If I try your code it does work... In which browser do you test it? I think the order of the prefixes is not quite right and an unprefixed keyframe is missing... "When writing CSS3 properties, the modern wisdom is to list the "real" property last and the vendor prefixes first:" SEE: https://css-tricks.com/ordering-css3-properties/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.dots{
    display: inline-block;
    animation-name: rotating;
    animation-duration: 1000ms;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;

     -webkit-animation-name: rotating;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;

    -moz-animation-name: rotating;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;

    -ms-animation-name: rotating;
    -ms-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.dots::after {
    content: "";
    background-image: url("/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/pub-crawl-edinburgh-hand-01.svg");
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
@keyframes rotating {
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-ms-keyframes rotating {
     0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes rotating {
     0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotating {
     0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

please double check the url of image.  and put the complete url of image like (http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/pub-crawl-edinburgh-hand-01.svg)

Hope this will help you..

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This worked perfectly. I don't suppose you could tell me how to move it left and right back and forth on repeat? I am trying to switch out the animation and it won't work again.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Rajkumar Gour is correct and works, but the original code did work for me in latest Firefox too!

I think you will maybe get some problems in specific browser versions because of wrong order of vendor prefixes, I've corrected that issue in the following snippet based on @Rajkumar Gours answer, but as said before the original code should work too...

"When writing CSS3 properties, the modern wisdom is to list the "real" property last and the vendor prefixes first..." See [css-tricks.com/ordering-css3-properties](https://css-tricks.com/ordering-css3-properties/) for further information!

```css
.dots{
    display: inline-block;

    -webkit-animation-name: rotating;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;

    -moz-animation-name: rotating;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;

    -ms-animation-name: rotating;
    -ms-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;

    animation-name: rotating;
    animation-duration: 1000ms;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.dots::after {
    content: "";
    background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/140x100");
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
@-ms-keyframes rotating {
     0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes rotating {
     0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotating {
     0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@keyframes rotating {
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="dots"></div>
```